# how do I open file to print lines?

Tags: perl

here is my script: Its supposed to be a hello world, display the last page you were on if your redirected I think, and display the source code of this page itself inside a div:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
BEGIN {
        $| = 1;
        open(STDERR, ">&STDOUT") ;
        #select(STDERR) ; $| = 1;
        #select(STDOUT) ; $| = 1;
        print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
}

print <<EndHTML1
<html>
<head>
<title>HEEYYYYY YOOOUUUU GUUUUYYYYSSSS!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<hr />
<p>You are accessing this page from $ENV{'HTTP_REFERER'}!</p>
<p>This page was written with perl and here is the source code:</p>
<div
style="background-color:#ABABAB;color:04FF00;margin:10px;border:5px;border-color:FF0000;width:100%;">
EndHTML1
if ( open(DATA, "< helloworld2.cgi")) { #it complains right here
        while (<DATA>) {
                print "<p>";
                print "$_";
                print "</p>\n";
        } # and here
}
else
{
        print "<p>Nope! Didn't work!</p>\n";
}
print <<EndHTML2
</div>
</body>
</html>
EndHTML2
```

It looks right to me. But IDK this is my first day seriously studying perl. FYI the file its reading is the script itself. I didn't think it would matter since its just supposed to read it. And its being interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a semicolon on the line

```
print <<EndHTML1
```

so it becomes

```
print <<EndHTML1;
```

Comment: That was the problem. As far as I can tell. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to put the open function outside your if block and remove the if-else block. Then put the Nope it didn't work message in a die function. The $! will tell you the error from your open function.

```
open(DATA, "< helloworld2.cgi") or die("Nope it didn't work : $!");
while (<DATA>) {
                print "<p>";
                print "$_";
                print "</p>\n";
} # and here
```